# Can I convert http client of Angular toPromise method into async and await?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have an `observable` in my **provider** that is converted into `promise` by using the `toPromise()` **method** example below:

```
getAllProvinces() {
      return this.http.get(`assets/ph/provinces.json`).toPromise()
  }
```

and in my **component** I would use **async and await** to return the value **asynchronously** example below:

```
async getAllProvince() {
    try {
      const provinces = await this.registerApi.getAllProvinces
      console.log(provinces)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    // this.registerApi.getAllProvinces().then(response => this.provinces = response).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

I also want to catch the error if something goes wrong.

Can someone shed some light for me convert my promise into **async and await** I still don't get the use of **async and await** I know it is just the evolution of **promises**.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use the correct angular tag when tagging

Comment: @mast3rd3mon sorry for that.

Comment: You're not calling the function. I think you need to use `await this.registerApi.getAllProvinces()`

Comment: @JeremyThille got it sorry for the question that is simple

Comment: No worries, we all make simple mistakes like this :)

Comment: @JeremyThille You might want to vote to close as off-topic/typo :-)

Answer (score 0):

So do this in

```
   getAllProvinces() {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     this.http.get(`assets/ph/provinces.json`).toPromise()
        .then((res: string[]) => {
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

this will convert http request to promise in angular.
Rest is same with just small change

```
async getAllProvince() {
    try {
      const provinces = await this.nameOftheService.getAllProvinces()
      console.log(provinces)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }

  }
```

this will work